# Which is the most elegant way to start celeryd in a Django project?

Tags: django, deployment, mod-wsgi, django-celery

I'm starting out with Celery in my Django project and couldn't help to wonder: which is the most elegant way to start to start Celery's workers for a project?

Let me explain the reasoning to this question.

Currently, the recommended way to start Celery seems to be `python manage.py celeryd` in simpler setups and something along the lines of `/etc/init.d/celeryd start` in more complex ones. However, in the first case, this process feels fragile since the process wouldn't start automatically, while the second require quite a bit of project-specific configuration (`virtualenv`, `settings` etc.) Especially the latter demonstrates my general feeling that a Celery worker is something deeply tied to the codebase it's part of and it's also deeply tied to the main project process, since a Celery worker without something to actually create tasks in it is practially useless (with one exception being `celerybeat`). Another problem with `init.d` scripts is that they'd need some advanced logic for handling several projects per server (with separate virtual environments, settings, paths etc.)

So I figured, it might be quite elegant configuration-wise to start `celeryd` together with my main process, e.g. spawn it from `mod_wsgi` withing Apache (similar for other setup options) and thus kill it when the main process goes down (`/etc/init.d/apache2 stop`). However, I'm not quite sure whether there are any technical traps considering performance and/or security in this reasoning -- it might as well be the case since I've tried googling this and found virtually nothing.

1. Is my reasoning flawed considering the Celery architecture?
2. Can I somehow spawn a `celeryd` from somewhere within `mod_wsgi` and is it sensible?
3. How do you start Celery workers in your projects?

Comment: Have a look at [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) for managing processes. On my server, I manage `nginx`,`gunicorn/uwsgi`, `postgres` and numerous django projects using it. It might be a good way of starting and stopping celery too

Answer (score 3):

I start celery using manage.py celeryd and managing that with supervisor.  On each deployment that modifies a task I simply restart celery after I've deployed and restarted apache.\

Edit:

We use chef to manage our configurations for supervisor and other processes, so this might be a bit over kill.  We have one master supervisord.conf that includes a separate configuration file for each site that we run.  One of those might look like this:

```
[program:celery_newproject]
command = /srv/www/.virtualenvs/newprojectenv/bin/python /srv/www/projects/newproject/manage.py celeryd --concurrency=2 --settings=settings.alpha --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celery_newproject.pid
user = wsgiuser
environment = PYTHON_EGG_CACHE="/tmp/.python-eggs"
```

On deploy then we just run

```
sudo supervisorctl restart celery_newproject
```

This restarts the supervisor process for celery and picks up any new tasks you've defined.

There are other non elegant ways to do this as well.  On my personal sites I just have a cron job running that checks for the existence of the .pid file and restarts celery if it doens't exist.  Not elegant at all, but it works for low reliability sites.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a `supervisord` example configuration? Your answer is a little thin.

Comment: Welcome to P.SE - to echo Martijn, please expand your answer to explain more fully.